# using left join empty value don't shown

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql-workbench

```
BEGIN
SELECT DISTINCT
caccounts.ACODE,
caccounts.TITLE,
feestructure.Amount
FROM
caccounts
LEFT OUTER JOIN feestructure ON caccounts.ACODE = feestructure.FeeHeadCode
where
feestructure.ACODE=aaa
GROUP BY feestructure.ACODE,feestructure.FeeHeadCode;
END
```

following is the inner join where 'aaa' value that taking at run time ...but the row having 'Amount' null is not showing 
if anyone know the solution then plz share with me. thanks

I've very low reputation thats why i cann't post the images

Comment: still not showing :(

Comment: 'aaa' is parameter in stored procedure

Comment: What is the value of the column `ACODE` for the row having `Amount` = NULL?

Comment: that row not showing having amount null

Comment: Do something like `select * from feestructure where amount is null`. Without knowing what the `ACODE` value is, we can't help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just remove where clause and place feestructure.ACode=aaa in left join

```
SELECT DISTINCT
feehead.ACODE,
feehead.TITLE,
feestructure.Amount
FROM
feehead
LEFT JOIN feestructure ON feestructure.FeeHeadCode = feehead.ACODE and feestructure.ACode=aaa
GROUP BY feehead.ACode,feehead.TITLE ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned the `Amount` column specifically, but that column being `null` should have no bearing on whether or not a record is displayed or not.

The most likely reason is that `ACODE` is also `null` for the particular record in question, and you need to change your `where` clause to specify that `ACODE` can be `null`:

```
... where (feestructure.ACODE = @aaa OR feestructure.ACODE IS null) ...
```

*(I'm assuming you're properly passing in "aaa" as a parameter to your query.)*

Comment: basically 'Acode' is P.K in 'account table' and that 'acode' used as 'Feeheadcode' or F.K in feestructure table... ans 'acode' in feestructure is another colum which is not related to value 'Acode' of  Account table

Answer (score 1):

Your WHERE clause of

feestructure.ACODE = aaa

will only return rows where the ACODE is aaa, which means that any row in caccounts that does not have a matching feestructure row will NOT get returned, because the ACODE for caccounts won't exist and is thus NOT aaa.

Therefore, you need to add a condition to your WHERE clause that accounts for that:

```
WHERE (feestructure.ACODE = aaa OR feestructure.ACODE IS NULL)
```

Comment: basically 'Acode' is P.K in 'account table' and that 'acode' used as 'Feeheadcode' or F.K in feestructure table... ans 'acode' in feestructure is another colum which is not related to value 'Acode' of Account table –